# Making DNG images available via USB in iOS

Tags: ios, file, usb, raw, dng

Currently when I connect an iOS device to a Linux computer, I can mount the photos directory as if it were a camera. However I can only access the JPEG photos, which are inherently low quality.

I were to write an iOS app that takes RAW photos, which are higher-quality than JPEGs, what file permissions flags or other attributes would I need to set to make them available via USB?

Comment: DNG files appear alongside JPG files when you connect the device via USB and allow access to photos.  Perhaps the application you are using on Linux doesn't show the DNG files because it doesn't understand the format, but if you just access the mounted file system, you will see that they are there.